# System.IO.Stream in Windows Phone

Tags: stream, windows-phone, azure-cognitive-services

I have to compare two faces (verify) in Windows Phone. For this, I am using [Face API](https://www.projectoxford.ai/face) to get `faceId` and compare the two `faceId`s. How to have that run in [Microsoft Project Oxford API Reference](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/54d85c1d5eefd00dc474a0ef/operations/54f0375749c3f70a50e79b82/console) with `application/octet-stream`, i.e., how to send `[Image File Binaries]`?

Also, I have implemented the sample solution given in [Microsoft Project Oxford Getting started with Face API in C#](https://www.projectoxford.ai/doc/face/Get-Started/csharp). The problem that I am encountering here is that I can't send the second parameter of `DetectAsync` as `Stream`. How to use `Stream` in Windows Phone application so as to have this application working? I have tried almost everything.

These are two different problems. First is of how to send the data in the doc page. Second is how to have the application running in Windows Phone.

Comment: Which version of Windows Phone are you targeting? 8.1 or Windows 10 UWP?

Comment: I am targeting Windows 8.1.

Comment: I could probably help you if it were a Windows 10 universal app, but not Phone 8.1 as that is about to disappear soon.

Comment: That time when I was working Windows 10 wasn't released.